# Python 3.4 hex to Japanese Characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-3.4

I am currently writing a script to pull information off my site which contains Japanese characters. So far I have my script pulling out the data off the site.

It has return as a string:

```
"\xe5\xb9\xb4\xe3\x81\xab\xe4\xb8\x80\xe5\xba\xa6\xe3\x81\xae\xe6\x99\xb4\xe3\x82\x8c\xe5\xa7\xbf"
```

Using an online hex to text tool, I am giving:

年に一度の晴れ姿

I know this phrase is correct, but my question is how do I convert it in python? When I run something like:

```
name = "\xe5\xb9\xb4\xe3\x81\xab\xe4\xb8\x80\xe5\xba\xa6\xe3\x81\xae\xe6\x99\xb4\xe3\x82\x8c\xe5\xa7\xbf"
print(name)
```

I am giving this:

```
å¹´ã«ä¸åº¦ã®æ´ãå§¿
```

I've tried to

```
name.decode("hex")
```

But it seems like Python 3.4 doesn't have `str.decode()`, so I tried to convert it to a bytes object and decode it that way, which still failed.

Edit 1:

Follow up question if you don't mind: Like the solution, Martijn Pieters gave this works:

```
name = "\xe2\x80\x9c\xe5\xa4\x8f\xe7\xa5\xad\xe3\x82\x8a\xe3\x83\x87\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x8‌​3\x88\xe2\x80\x9d\xe7\xb5\xa2\xe7\x80\xac \xe7\xb5\xb5\xe9\x87\x8c" 
name = name.encode('latin1') 
print(name.decode('Utf-8'))
```

However if I have what's in the quotes for name in a file and I do this:

```
with open('0N.txt',mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    name = f.read() 
name = name.encode('latin1') 
print(name.decode('Utf-8'))
```

It doesn't work...any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing the Python *representation* with the contents. You are shown `\xhh` hex escapes used in Python string literals to keep the displayed value ASCII safe and reproducable.

You have UTF-8 data here:

```
>>> name = b"\xe5\xb9\xb4\xe3\x81\xab\xe4\xb8\x80\xe5\xba\xa6\xe3\x81\xae\xe6\x99\xb4\xe3\x82\x8c\xe5\xa7\xbf"
>>> name.decode('utf8')
'\u5e74\u306b\u4e00\u5ea6\u306e\u6674\u308c\u59ff'
>>> print(name.decode('utf8'))
年に一度の晴れ姿
```

Note that I used a `bytes()` string literal there, using `b'...'`. If your data is *not* a `bytes` object you have a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) and need to encode to bytes first:

```
name.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

Latin 1 maps codepoints one-on-one to bytes, so that's usually a safe bet to use in case of such data. It could be that you have a Mojibake in a different codec, it depends on how you retrieved the data.

If used `open()` to read the data from a file, you either specified the wrong `encoding` or relied on your platform default. use `open(filename, encoding='utf8')` to remedy that.

If you used the `requests` library to load this from a website, take into account that the `response.text` attribute uses `latin-1` as the default codec if a) the site didn't specify a codec and b) the response has a `text/*` mime-type. If this is sourced from HTML, usually the codec is part of the HTML headers instead. Use a library like BeautifulSoup to handle HTML (using the `response.content` raw bytes) and it'll detect such information for you.

If all else fails, the [`ftfy` library](http://ftfy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) may still be able to fix a Mojibake; it uses specially constructed codecs to reverse common errors.