# From hexadecimal string to character (jis encoding)

Tags: python, encoding

I have an hexadecimal string "\x98\x4F" that is the JIS encoding of the japanese kanji 楼.
How can I print the kanji in python starting from the encoding?
I tried

```
print b'\x98\x4F'.encode('euc_jp')
```

but without success...
any clue?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2 use `str.decode()` with the `shift-jis` encoding:

```
>>> s = "\x98\x4F".decode('shift-jis')
>>> s
u'\u697c'
>>> print s
楼
```

This *decodes* the jis encoded data into a Python unicode string. Printing that string displays the required character, provided that your default encoding can do so.

In Python 3 you can prefix the encoded string with `b`:

```
>>> s = b"\x98\x4F".decode('shift-jis')
>>> s
'楼'
>>> print(s)
楼
```

(this will also work in Python 2)

Comment: Can add this for python 3.4? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235201/python-3-4-hex-to-japanese-characters

Comment: @Raskayu: OP is using Python 2, but I have already added code for Python 3.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!  Alternatively `print(b"\x98\x4F".decode('cp932'));` did the same thing for me in Python 3.8